# How to disable Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio for education purposes?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Because the coding-test of my university must be written by hand (on paper), I want to disable the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio. So I can train this scenario.

I can change colors of the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio. But doing this for every type of code is a lot of work.

Would be great if someone knows an easier solution, for just disabling Syntax highlighting. By the way, I am programming in C.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your code into Notepad, or any other text editor that doesn't support syntax highlighting.